# JavaScript - gallery - lighbtox - only half screen goes black in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok guys, please don't kill me, it's my first question here and I know very little about programming :)
So I wanted to create a simple website with lightbox gallery, you can have a look at it [here](http://dekarstwo-guszczynski.net16.net/galeria.html).

So the issue I can't solve is that when you scroll down the page there is no black background behind a photo.

I've tried changing overlay setting in CSS to height 100% but it doesn't make any difference.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me or at leat point me in a right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: You can simply close the image lightbox when the page is scrolled, if you want.

Comment: your link is dead and you don't mention which gallery code are you using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `#overlay`'s position to `fixed` instead of `absolute` in your css and it's done!

Comment: `galeriacss.css:27` to be precise

Comment: Thank you Sir! Worked like a charm :)